# Tensorflow: How to get the Expected input image size form tensor flow Model(Attention OCR Model)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Have got the input node name and output node name from `Tensor Board Graph`, but couldn't find the expected input image size for `Attention OCR Model`. As mentioned mobile net base model has 224x224.

`Tensor flow Version : 1.3.0`

`Tensor Board : 1.12`

Please help me to find the expected input image size from the `Model Output`.

Here is the gibHub link of the `Attention OCR Model`:

[OCR github Link](https://github.com/pannous/tensorflow-ocr)

[Attention OCR Model from AOCR Tensorflow package](https://github.com/emedvedev/attention-ocr)

[image: tensorboard-graph-picture]

```
# Name of the input node
INPUT_NODE_NAME=shuffle_batch 

# Name of the output node specified during transfer learning                    
OUTPUT_NODE_NAME=sequence_loss_fn/SLF/unstack_1
    
# Expected input image size. For mobilenet base model 224x224
IMGSIZE=7
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the custom implementations, but the attention `OCR` in the tensorflow research repository uses an input `'image_shape': (150, 600, 3)`,

it can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr):

I've used this implementation on several projects to extract custom characters from images and it works quite well.